# why is ```long int``` not working on turbo c

Tags: c, data-structures, long-integer, unsigned, turbo-c

Our teacher requires us to use turbo c on our assignments. The program is working fine on other compiler applications but it doesn't with turbo c. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


struct Name
{
    char last[100];
    char first[100];
};

struct Address
{
    char province[100];
    int zipCode;
};

struct PBEntry
{
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    int age;
    long int mobile;
}pb[10];

void showAll(struct PBEntry *p, int SIZE);


int main()
{
    
    int choice = 1, SIZE=0, c=0, j;
    clrscr();
    printf("Welcome to Phonebook Application\n");
    while(choice != 4 )
    {
        struct PBEntry *p;
        struct PBEntry edit[10];
        
         
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    
        switch(choice)
        { 
            case 1:

                printf("Enter Entry %d\n", SIZE);
                printf("Enter full name: ");
                gets(pb[SIZE].name.first); 
                gets(pb[SIZE].name.last);
                printf("Enter province: ");
                gets(pb[SIZE].address.province);
                printf("Enter ZIP code: ");
                scanf("%d", &pb[SIZE].address.zipCode);
                printf("Enter age: ");
                scanf("%d", &pb[SIZE].age);
                printf("Enter mobile number: ");
                scanf("%ld", &pb[SIZE].mobile);
                SIZE++;
                break;
                
            case 2:
                printf("What entry number to edit?: ");
                scanf("%d", &j);
                printf("Change Entry %d\n", j);
                printf("Change full name: ");
                gets(pb[j].name.first); 
                gets(pb[j].name.last);
                printf("Change province: ");
                gets(pb[j].address.province);
                printf("Change ZIP code: ");
                scanf("%d", &pb[j].address.zipCode);
                printf("Change age: ");
                scanf("%d", &pb[j].age);
                printf("Change mobile number: ");
                scanf("%ld", &pb[j].mobile);
                c++;
 
            case 3:    
            showAll(pb, SIZE);    
            break;
 
            case 4:    
            exit(0);
        
        }
    }
    
    
getch();

}



void showAll(struct PBEntry *p, int SIZE)
{
    struct PBEntry edit[10];
    int i=0, c=0;
    while(i != SIZE)
    {
        if(c>0)
        {
            
            p = &edit;
    
                printf("Entry %d\n", i);
                printf("Name:         %s %s\n", p[i].name.first, p[i].name.last);
                printf("Province:     %s\n", p[i].address.province);
                printf("ZIP code:     %d\n", p[i].address.zipCode);
                printf("Age:          %d\n", p[i].age);
                printf("Phone number: %ld\n", p[i].mobile);
                printf("\n");
                 
        }
        else
        {
            
            p = &pb;
            {
                printf("Entry %d\n", i);
                printf("Name:         %s %s\n", p[i].name.first, p[i].name.last);
                printf("Province:     %s\n", p[i].address.province);
                printf("ZIP code:     %d\n", p[i].address.zipCode);
                printf("Age:          %d\n", p[i].age);
                printf("Phone number: %ld\n", p[i].mobile);
                printf("\n");
                
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}



int printMenu()
{    
printf("\n1. Add Entry\n");  
printf("2.Edit Entry\n");   
printf("3 Show All\n");  
printf("4 Exit\n");
}
```

Our phone number here has 11 digits, or 12 at maximum. But long int, and even unsigned lont in, does not work on turbo c. I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: Maybe represent phone number as a string?

Comment: An 11-12 digit number is going to require 34-37 bits, and so will not fit into the 32-bit `long int` on Turbo C.

Comment: Regular int in Turbo C is 16-bit, and long int is 32-bit. Better use string.

Comment: Also, just so you know: you'll be having lots of other problems with that compiler, which is seriously out of date.  Good luck.

Comment: i guess I have no choice then. I think it is better to have a deduction on not following instructions than having no right outputs hahahahuhuhu

Comment: Phone numbers can begin with zero, even more than one, and integers cannot have this information.

Comment: Don't use tools that are older than you. But I imagine your school told you to use Turbo C for whatever obscure reason.

Comment: Yeah @Jabberwocky. We were required to use Turbo C. What a bummer.

Comment: @PABLO1403 out of curiosity, what kind of school is it and in which country?

Comment: UP Tacloban college in the Philippines @Jabberwocky.

Comment: Similarly `gets` has been obsolete for ages. If your teacher is telling you to use it, they have very outdated knowledge.